# How to link my sql data on both android and web?

Tags: android, sql, android-studio, cpanel

**How to make them access the same database?**
*I have a web and mobile application and I need them to access the msm sql file to do the crud*

> the problem is that one of them I stored in godaddy and the other one I'm thinking of storing in firebase what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can create API and sync both Android Database or you can sync with [Socket](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket) without using API

Answer (score 0):

You should create an API in order to achieve that because there isnt any connection between your firebase database and your MySql database(If it is MySql database).Therefor you cant sync them or use both of them.I dont understand why do you want to use both of them because you can use one database and use api to access database from your web app and your application.Here is a link :
[what is an api](https://www.altexsoft.com/blog/engineering/what-is-api-definition-types-specifications-documentation/)

What you are trying to do increases the complexity of your code because using two different databases and trying to sync them is nothing but an effortless try,And by doing that you have to think about different aspects of your apps functionality, for example if a user register in your web app he or she should be able to sign in your android app right away (which means your databases should always watch for new data and act fast) and your codes should be very optimal in order to achieve that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).